# What wrong is the computing of scalar curvature of $T^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

As a practice, I compute the scalar curvature of $T^2$ with induced metric of $R^3$.
First,give a coordinate
$$
u:(x,y)\rightarrow((3+\cos x)\cos y, (3+\cos x)\sin y, \sin x)
$$
Then
$$
\partial_xu=(-\sin x \cos y,-\sin x\sin y,\cos x)  \\
\partial_y u=(-(3+\cos x)\sin y,(3+\cos x)\cos y ,0)
$$
Then,metric is 
$$
g_{11}=1   \\
g_{22}= (3+\cos x)^2  \\
others =0
$$
Then the Christoffel is 
$$
\Gamma^x_{xx}=-\frac{\sin x}{3+\cos x}~~~~~~others=0
$$

Then ,curvature Tensor is zero, Ricci tensor is zero, and Scalar curvature is zero. But by Gauss-Bonnet theorem, there is not a metric of scalar curvature identity to  zero on $T^2$.What wrong is there ?

Comment: That's mean you computed wrong. Compact surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ must have a point with positive $K$. On the other hand, if your $T$ is not embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, it is entirely possible that $R = 0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar  I know I must have done some wrong, but I can't found it .

Comment: Is $x$ meant to be the first coordinate? Looks to me like you should get $g_{11}=0$, maybe you've mixed them up. Side note: Gauss-Bonnet actually tells you that $\mathbb T^2$ is the *only* compact surface that *can* be given a flat metric, since it has zero Euler characteristic.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis There is some  write errors, I have rewrite it . $x$ is the first coordinate. I compute the $g_{11}=\langle\partial_xu,\partial _xu\rangle$.so ,the $g_{11}=1$

Comment: Then you should get non-zero Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^1_{22}$, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Yes,there is wrong.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anthony, I have done some wrong in my compute, there is a result by software

[image]